# Reading from file, tokenizing, and store in hashmap, then extract information from hasmap to create database and tables

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I have a text file that looks like this:

```text
Pro Market
key- id
Krest - item, fee
Buys - id, item, price
```

The Java program is to read the above text file, tokenize it, and probable store it in a `HashMap`. Then retrieve the words from the `HashMap` to create a database name Market; and tables name key, Krest, and Buys. And each of the tables will have their corresponding attributes as listed corresponding. That is table Key has id as attribute, Krest has item and fee; while Buys has id, item, and price.

Please who can help with good insight.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me a case of object oriented mapping.

You need to read data, insert them to a data structure like a HashMap(as objects, that's the key point) and then by using ORM technologies, like [hibernate](http://hibernate.org/) insert them to a database.

A nice tutorial on hibernate can be found [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/hibernate-tutorials/)

Comment: Thanks but can I have a snippet of the code please.

Comment: I am afraid it is not something I can describe in one post. You can find plenty of examples in the tutorial pointed in my post.